# React Native: How to set background color for the whole app and individual scene in react-native-router-flux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

In React Native using react-native-router-flux, How can I set the background color for the whole app and also individual scene as well?

Here is my current set up:

```
const RouterWithRedux = connect()(Router)
const store = configureStore()

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RouterWithRedux>
          <Scene key='root'>
            <Scene initial={true} key='login' component={Login} title='Login Page'/>
            <Scene key='register' component={Register} title='Register'/>
          </Scene>
        </RouterWithRedux>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: @rclai could you help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39611987/react-native-react-native-router-flux-how-to-apply-hidenavbar-to-only-one-sc

Answer (score 3):

In the [API documentation](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API_CONFIGURATION.md), you can use `sceneStyle` or `getSceneStyle` on both `Router` and `Scene` (only `getSceneStyle` for `Router` though).

**EDIT**

In the `Router` you can only use `getSceneStyle` and you must pass a *function*:

```
// ..
const getSceneStyle = (/* NavigationSceneRendererProps */ props, computedProps) => {
  const style = {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  };
  return style;
};
// ..
<Router getSceneStyle={getSceneStyle} {...otherProps}>
// ..
```

For your `Scene`s you can just pass an object or `StyleSheet` object to `sceneStyle` or use `getSceneStyle` (making sure you pass a function like above):

```
<Scene
  key="my-scene"
  component={MyScene}
  sceneStyle={{
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  }}
  title="My Scene"  />
```

This will override the blue background.

Comment: Sorry but could you show how it would apply to the code that I have? I tried but didn't work.

Comment: `const RouterWithRedux = connect()(<Router styleStyle={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}/>)`

Comment: hi have you had the chance to see my previous comment?

Comment: Router didn't work so for each Scene did `<Scene component={Login} initial={true} key='login' sceneStyle={{backgroundColor: 'black'}} title='Login'/>` and worked. But wondering if you are not allowed to set `sceneStyle` on the `<Scene key='root'/>`? Because it does not work. Seems like doing for each Scene is overwork. Also, even if I set backgroundColor to black, during transition seems like there is another background which is white. How can you change the color for that as well? Thank you rclai and will take the answer once answered.

Comment: You can look at my updated answer. I ran the example project that `react-native-router-flux` has and was able to verify that it works. Also, I don't know if you noticed, but in your previous comment, you were saying how you tried setting the style on your `RouterWithRedux`, but you had a typo and wrote `styleStyle` when you meant `sceneStyle`, nevertheless, even if you corrected your typo, you still had to use `getSceneStyle` and pass a function.